# Crea un directorio pero no aparece y también no reconoce la ruta

Tags: python-3.x, os

al correr el script me dice que ha creado ya el directorio y que no se puede crear un directorio con el mismo nombre. Pero nunca se me crea ninguna nueva carpeta ni nada en ninguna parte de mi pc.    Llevo rato matandome con esto y no entiendo el por que me pasa,  alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

image_folder = sys.argv[1]
output_folder = sys.argv[2]

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(directory)


for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
    clean_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    img = Image.open(f'{image_folder}{filename}')
    # added the / in case user doesn't enter it. You may want to check for this and add or remover it.
    img.save(f'{directory}/{clean_name}.png', 'png')
    print('all done!')
```

He actualizado un poco el código, ahora el problema que tengo es que no me reconoce la ruta o la carpeta que quiero que revise como el primer argumento.

```
 C:\Users\Keeper Lifeblood\Desktop\images>python JPGtoPNG_Converter.py /images /new
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Keeper Lifeblood\Desktop\images\JPGtoPNG_Converter.py", line 12, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: '/images'
```

Si dejo solo la siguiente sección de código me sigue dando el problema:

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

image_folder = sys.argv[1]
output_folder = sys.argv[2]

# print(os.path.exists(output_folder))
print(image_folder, output_folder)
```

Al introducir el comando `>python JPGtoPNG_Converter.py /Images /new` obtengo:
/Images /new

Hasta aquí todo bien. Pero cuando verifico los folders con el código:

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

image_folder = sys.argv[1]
output_folder = sys.argv[2]

print(os.path.exists(output_folder))
```

Obtengo: ***True***  diciendome que el folder **new** existe, pero no se me ha creado ninguna carpeta en ningun lado.  Entonces si lo lelvo al código completo deja de reconocerme la carpeta donde está todo que es la ***/Images*** dándome el error ya mencionado:

```
 C:\Users\Keeper Lifeblood\Desktop\images>python JPGtoPNG_Converter.py /images /new
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Keeper Lifeblood\Desktop\images\JPGtoPNG_Converter.py", line 12, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: '/images'`
```

Comment: Falta que muestres el comando ("python pgma.py par1 par2"), el directorio actual y el resultado de la ejecución.

Comment: `python JPGtoPNG_Converter.py /images /new`   ese es el comando que estoy dando, pero no me reconoce el argv[1] que debería ser la carpeta que contiene las imagenes.

Comment: Encontré donde me está creando las carpetas, me las crea en el disco local C:.      Cómo puedo hacer para que me las cree en la carpeta donde se encuentran las imagenes y como hago para que el os.argv[1] me reconozca dicha carpeta?

Comment: `/images`: La barra al comienzo indica la raíz del disco . Probablemente debas omitirlas si son subdirectorios

Comment: cómo puedo omitirlas si salen siempre en la consola? debo primero buscar el directorio donde se encuentra el script.py para ejecutarlo